# combine array if any value is found duplicates php

Tags: php

I am working with a one dimensional array in PHP. I would like to detect the presence of duplicate values, then count the number of duplicate values and out put the results. For example, given the following array:

**Original Array:**

```
Array
    {
        "OrderId": "1",
        "ProductOrderedId": "1",
        "CallerId": "1",
    },
    {
        "OrderId": "2",
        "ProductOrderedId": "2",
        "CallerId": "2",
    },
    {
        "OrderId": "2",
        "ProductOrderedId": "3",
        "CallerId": "2",
    }
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
   Array
   {
            "OrderId": "1",
            "ProductOrderedId": "1",
            "CallerId": "1",
        },
        {
            "OrderId": "2",
            "ProductOrderedId": "2,3",
            "CallerId": "2",
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code hope this helpful for you.

```
    $newArrayData = array();
        $valuesProduct = array();
        foreach ($fetchData as $key => $value) {

          if (count($value) > 1) {
                foreach ($value as $keys => $vals) {
                    $valuesProduct[] = $vals['ProductOrderedId'];
                }
                $implodeVal=implode(',',$valuesProduct);
              $newArrayData[]=  array('OrderId' => $value[0]['OrderId'], 'CallerId' => $value[0]['CallerId'], 
"ProductOrderedId" => $implodeVal);

            } else {
                $newArrayData[]=array('OrderId' => $value[0]['OrderId'], 'CallerId' => $value[0]['CallerId'], 
 "ProductOrderedId" => $value[0]['ProductOrderedId']);
            }
        }
        print_r($newArrayData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this if you find it simple.

```
$values = array(
    array(
        "OrderId"=> "1",
        "ProductOrderedId"=> "1",
        "CallerId"=> "1",
    ),
    array(
        "OrderId"=> "4",
        "ProductOrderedId"=> "2",
        "CallerId"=> "2",
    ),
    array(
        "OrderId"=> "4",
        "ProductOrderedId"=> "3",
        "CallerId"=> "2",
    )
);

$temp=array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    if(isset($temp[$value["OrderId"]])){
        $temp[$value["OrderId"]]["ProductOrderedId"]=$temp[$value["OrderId"]]["ProductOrderedId"].",".$value["ProductOrderedId"];   
    }else{
        $temp[$value["OrderId"]]=$value;        
    }
}

$final_array= array_values($temp);
```